# Google Maps Pin on Wrong Lat,Long and Zooming In and Out changes pin location

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am facing an issue on Google maps where the initial location of the pin is dropped at the wrong location even with the right Lat and Long provided. Also, when I zoom in and out of the map, the pin will disappear and reappear at another location which is wrong as well.

Images for better explanation: [Images](http://imgur.com/gallery/FcmgW)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.plotCoordinates = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var mapCanvas = $(element).parent().find('.map-canvas')[0];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    var mapOptions = {

        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

    for (var index in bindingContext.$data.AnalyticsData().LocationInfo()) {
        var eachLocation = bindingContext.$data.AnalyticsData().LocationInfo()[index];

        var image = "/Images/Location-Icon-Blue copy.png";

        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(eachLocation.Latitude(), eachLocation.Longitude());
        console.log("lat: "+eachLocation.Latitude());
        console.log("long: "+eachLocation.Longitude());
        bounds.extend(position);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            icon: image
        });
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }

    // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function (event) {
        this.setZoom(15);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

}
```

}

Comment: Code itself would be better indeed... What's most beautiful would be a jsFiddle though.. And welcome to SO, remember to take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help to see how to use the site.

Comment: Maybe you've defined the anchor wrong for your icon? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Icon

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it. There was a css:

```
canvas{ 
    width:400px;
    height:600px;
}
```

that was making the marker skewed.